# What kind of html element is that?

Tags: html

i look trough zalando product catalouge and want to know what kind of element is that:

```
<z-grid-itemtem>
```

In what type og html element are products injected?
https://www.zalando.de/herren/?q=Nike+Air+Max

Comment: It's a custom component, provided by a framework like React, Angular, Polymer, Vue, Web Components, etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's called a custom element.
Basically, it's not an element integrated into HTML 5 by default, but it was created using JavaScript that emulates it using native functions.

If you want to do something similar, there is [PolymerJS](https://www.polymer-project.org), and some UI JS libraries do something similar ([DisplayJS](https://display.js.org) for example).
If you don't want to use these libraries, there is a way to do it in ES6: [MDN -  Custom Elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Custom_Elements)

Hope it will help you .

Answer (score 0):

Z-grid is a grid/styling framework (like Bootstrap). [More about z-grid here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/z-grid)

Answer (score -2):

There are no standard HTML elements with hyphens in their names, but that is the convention used by the [custom elements specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/) (currently only a working draft) with [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=custom-elements) (although it does lend itself to JS polyfills).